# How to create a collapsible div using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have added a collapsible div to my images. It is working for only one image.

If I add another image it is not working:

```js
function expand(showHideDiv, switchTextDiv) {
  
  var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);
  var text = document.getElementById(switchTextDiv);
  if (ele.style.display == "block") {
    ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = "+";
  } else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    text.innerHTML = "-";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="expand">Chart1<a id="expand" href="javascript:expand('expand-content','expand');" >+</a></h1>
<div id="expand-content" style="display: none;">
  <img src="imagelink" width="100%">
</div>

<h1 class="expand">Chart2<a id="expand" href="javascript:expand('expand-content','expand');" >+</a></h1>
<div id="expand-content" style="display: none;">
  <img src="imagelink" width="100%">
</div>
```

Comment: Please use different ID for each image you cant have same ID for both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using jquery for it. It is much easier.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jansian/vuz46sLc/

**HTML Code:**

```
<a href="#" class="lnkToggle"><h1>BMR Chart +</h1></a>
<div class="collapse" style="display: none;">
  <img src="http://www.labwise.in/devel/media/bmr.jpg" width="100%">
</div>

<a href="#" class="lnkToggle"><h1>BMI Chart +</h1></a>
<div class="collapse" style="display: none;">
  <img src="http://www.labwise.in/devel/media/BMI_Chart.png" width="100%">
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(".lnkToggle").click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use different id tag.

```
<h1  class="expand">BMR Chart<a id="expand" href="javascript:expand('expand-content','expand');" >+</a></h1>
<div id="expand-content" style="display: none;"><img src="http://www.labwise.in/devel/media/bmr.jpg" width="100%"></div>

 <h1  class="expand">BMI Chart<a id="expand2" href="javascript:expand('expand-content2','expand2');" >+</a></h1>
 <div id="expand-content2" style="display: none;"><img src="http://www.labwise.in/devel/media/BMI_Chart.png" width="100%"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking a look at your code ... Its not good to add same id values for different elements. Change the id values to some other values and try the same javascript code with new values.